# How to update table after dismissing previous view controller?

Tags: swift

So I have a table view populated with data, when clicking on a cell I go to another view controller where I delete the selected cell object. After deleted, the view controller goes back to the table view controller but the table view does not update. How can I fix that?

```
@IBAction func deleteUser(_ sender: Any) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Delete user", message:
           "Are you sure you want to delete this user?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive,  handler: { action in
        // self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LogoutID", sender: nil)
        print("User ID\(self.userID)")
        self.backEnd.deleteJSONUser(query: self.userID,completion: {(err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to delete",err)
                return
            }
            print("Successfully deleted user")

        })
        // self.dismiss(animated: true)
        //goes back to previous table with all users
        self.instanceOfVCA.usersTableView.reloadData()
        //self.instanceOfVCA.users.remove(at: Int(self.userID)!)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

     }))

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I already tried WillApear:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){

    usersTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Guess your model used in table didnot update

Comment: To refresh the tableview, you also need to remove an object from your array which is used to populate a tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are deleting the data from your backend but you are not also deleting it from whatever array or database that backs your table view.  You need to notify the VC with the tableView to delete the item AND reload (or just call the deleteRow method).  You can do this with a protocol and delegate, a notification, a database subscription or a completion handler.